# Kotlin removeAt skips 1 value per iteration?

Tags: kotlin

I'm implementing a pagination function, that puts items into a MutableList with add(index,item), and when a size threshold is reached a number of items are removed with removeAt(index), starting at index 0 to n. Then more items are added and so on.
Heres a debug log, the behavior is just weird.

```
D: add(index,item) INDEX = 0, value is = VALUE 1
D: ##############
D: add(index,item) INDEX = 1, value is = VALUE 2
D: ##############
D: add(index,item) INDEX = 2, value is = VALUE 3
D: ##############
D: add(index,item) INDEX = 3, value is = VALUE 4
D: ##############
D: add(index,item) INDEX = 4, value is = VALUE 5
D: ##############
D: ************************************************************
D: add(index,item) INDEX = 5, value is = VALUE 6
D: ##############
D: add(index,item) INDEX = 6, value is = VALUE 7
D: ##############
D: add(index,item) INDEX = 7, value is = VALUE 8
D: ##############
D: add(index,item) INDEX = 8, value is = VALUE 9
D: ##############
D: add(index,item) INDEX = 9, value is = VALUE 10
D: ##############
D: ************************************************************
D: add(index,item) INDEX = 10, value is = VALUE 11
D: ##############
D: add(index,item) INDEX = 11, value is = VALUE 12
D: ##############
D: add(index,item) INDEX = 12, value is = VALUE 13
D: ##############
D: add(index,item) INDEX = 13, value is = VALUE 14
D: ##############
D: add(index,item) INDEX = 14, value is = VALUE 15
D: ##############
D: ************************************************************
D: add(index,item) INDEX = 15, value is = VALUE 16
D: ##############
D: add(index,item) INDEX = 16, value is = VALUE 17
D: ##############
D: add(index,item) INDEX = 17, value is = VALUE 18
D: ##############
D: add(index,item) INDEX = 18, value is = VALUE 19
D: ##############
D: add(index,item) INDEX = 19, value is = VALUE 20
D: ##############
D: ************************************************************
D: NOW THRESHOLD IS REACHED, ORDER OF FINAL MUTABLE LIST IS...
D: ITEM AT INDEX = 0 IS = VALUE 1
D: ##############
D: ITEM AT INDEX = 1 IS = VALUE 2
D: ##############
D: ITEM AT INDEX = 2 IS = VALUE 3
D: ##############
D: ITEM AT INDEX = 3 IS = VALUE 4
D: ##############
D: ITEM AT INDEX = 4 IS = VALUE 5
D: ##############
D: ITEM AT INDEX = 5 IS = VALUE 6
D: ##############
D: ITEM AT INDEX = 6 IS = VALUE 7
D: ##############
D: ITEM AT INDEX = 7 IS = VALUE 8
D: ##############
D: ITEM AT INDEX = 8 IS = VALUE 9
D: ##############
D: ITEM AT INDEX = 9 IS = VALUE 10
D: ##############
D: ITEM AT INDEX = 10 IS = VALUE 11
D: ##############
D: ITEM AT INDEX = 11 IS = VALUE 12
D: ##############
D: ITEM AT INDEX = 12 IS = VALUE 13
D: ##############
D: ITEM AT INDEX = 13 IS = VALUE 14
D: ##############
D: ITEM AT INDEX = 14 IS = VALUE 15
D: ##############
D: ITEM AT INDEX = 15 IS = VALUE 16
D: ##############
D: ITEM AT INDEX = 16 IS = VALUE 17
D: ##############
D: ITEM AT INDEX = 17 IS = VALUE 18
D: ##############
D: ITEM AT INDEX = 18 IS = VALUE 19
D: ##############
D: ITEM AT INDEX = 19 IS = VALUE 20
D: ##############
D: *************************************************************
D: removeAt(index) = 0, value is = VALUE 1
D: ##############
D: removeAt(index) = 1, value is = VALUE 3
D: ##############
D: removeAt(index) = 2, value is = VALUE 5
D: ##############
D: removeAt(index) = 3, value is = VALUE 7
D: ##############
D: removeAt(index) = 4, value is = VALUE 9
D: ##############
D: removeAt(index) = 5, value is = VALUE 11
D: ##############
D: removeAt(index) = 6, value is = VALUE 13
D: ##############
D: removeAt(index) = 7, value is = VALUE 15
D: ##############
D: removeAt(index) = 8, value is = VALUE 17
D: ##############
D: removeAt(index) = 9, value is = VALUE 19
D: ##############
```

So here my threshold is 20 items, and i drop 10, but as you can see the indexes are not the same for some reason, even though i have not applied any other method in between...

heres how i add items, i modified it to show the log, before i was using addAll(list), but the behavior is still the same with add(index, item)

```
if (status == SUCCESS) {
                val i = if (pageSnapshotHolder.isNotEmpty()) pageSnapshotHolder.lastIndex+1 else 0
                var index = i
                for (item in data.content!!) {
                    pageSnapshotHolder.add(index,item)
                    Log.d("PaginationManager", "ADDING ITEM AT INDEX = $index, value is = ${item.title}")
                    Log.d("PaginationManager","##############")
                    index++
                }
                Log.d("PaginationManager","****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************")
            }
```

And here is how i remove items

```
 if (pageSnapshotHolder.size > 15) {

                Log.d("PaginationManager", "NOW THRESHOLD IS REACHED, ORDER OF FINAL MUTABLE LIST IS...")
                for ((index, item) in pageSnapshotHolder.withIndex()) {
                    Log.d("PaginationManager","ITEM AT INDEX = $index IS = ${item.title}")
                    Log.d("PaginationManager","##############")
                }
                Log.d("PaginationManager","****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************")

                for (index in 0..10) {
                    val a = pageSnapshotHolder.removeAt(index)
                    Log.d("PaginationManager", "DROPPING ITEM AT INDEX = $index, value is = ${a.title}")
                    Log.d("PaginationManager","##############")
                } 
                Log.d("PaginationManager","****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************")
            }
```

Comment: This isn't a bug in Kotlin, but your code: `removeAt` _shifts all the indexes over_ of the remaining elements, but your code doesn't account for the next value being at the _same_ position.

Comment: i get it now, so because the list is shriking per every iteration of for loop, then the next index expected gets behind, thanks!!, what i should do is instead run the loop but remove  alway index 0 i guess

Answer (score 0):

This happens naturally because you're incrementing the delete index by only 1 each time, not accounting for the fact that values greater than the one deleted have now "shifted down" (shifted up visually below) in the array:

Here's what's going on visually:

Before delete:

```
Index  Value
0      1
1      2
2      3
3      4
4      5
5      6
...
```

Delete item at index 0 = Value "1" (per above)

```
Index  Value
0      2
1      3
2      4
3      5
4      6
...
```

Delete item at index 1 = Value "3" (per above)

```
Index  Value
0      2
1      4
2      5
3      6
...
```

Delete item at index 2 = Value "5" (per above)

etc...

Answer (score 0):

As Louis pointed out, the indexes shift when an item is removed of the list, so instead of iterating like

```
for(i in 0..10) { list.removeAt(i)}
```

I should do like

```
for(i in 0..10) {list.removeAt(0)}
```

Comment: Since you aren’t using `i` you could use `repeat(11)` instead of `for (i in 0..10)`. If you’re frequently removing from the beginning of the list, it will likely be more efficient to use a LinkedList and use `removeFirst()`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 yep, im definitely removing and adding lists a lot, and from both sides actually, from the beggining, and also from the end. Do you mind giving a little snippet with linkedList ?

Comment: A snippet of doing what with it? You can replace `removeAt(0)` with `removeFirst()` when using a LinkedList.